# Regular expression to retrieve a string from a multiline file text

Tags: regex, bash, sh

I am searching for a way to extract the peer IP by looking for the secret of that peer.

Example:

```
peer 1.2.3.10 {
    authentication {
        mode pre-shared-secret
        pre-shared-secret SecretPasswordA
    }
    connection-type initiate
    ike-group IKE_1.2.3.4
    local-address 6.7.8.9
    vti {
        bind vti64
        esp-group ESP_1.2.3.4
    }
}
peer 1.2.3.20 {
    authentication {
        mode pre-shared-secret
        pre-shared-secret SecretPasswordB
    }
    connection-type initiate
    ike-group IKE_1.2.3.4
    local-address 6.7.8.9
    vti {
        bind vti64
        esp-group ESP_1.2.3.4
    }
}
peer 1.2.3.30 {
    authentication {
        mode pre-shared-secret
        pre-shared-secret SecretPasswordC
    }
    connection-type initiate
    ike-group IKE_1.2.3.4
    local-address 6.7.8.9
    vti {
        bind vti64
        esp-group ESP_1.2.3.4
    }
}
```

Provided I know SecrePasswordB, I would need to retrieve the peer IP which is 1.2.3.20, of empty if not found (or anything else easy to identify.

The text comes from a shell command into a variable (ie. `TEXT=$(command_string)`).

As I only have a basic shell and few tool available on the system that would need to be done with very basic linux tools. And here I am stuck not finding a solution...

Comment: What shell? What tools? Do you have awk or perl? This is a cumbersome problem to solve with e.g. bash alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is formatted into separate lines as shown in the question then a simple shell script suffices. Simply split input into a leading word followed by the rest. Save the IP whenever a "peer" line is read. Print the most recent IP if the secret is read.

**getPeerIP**:

```
#!/bin/sh

secret="$1"

while read -r arg1 rest; do
    case "$arg1" in
        peer)
            ip="${rest% *}" # prune everything after first space
            ;;
        pre-shared-secret)
            if [ "$rest" = "$secret" ]; then
                echo "$ip"
                exit # don't bother reading rest of file
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Usage:

```
command_string | getPeerIP 'Secret Password'
```

Comment: Maybe not a single line but works and is I admit it is much easier to understand. Thanks to @tshiono for the RegEx tough!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a variable `TEXT` assigned to the whole lines provided
as an example, would you please try:

```
secret="SecretPasswordB"        # or assign to your actual string
secret=$(printf %q "$secret")   # escape metacharacters just in case

pat='peer[[:blank:]]+(([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3})[[:blank:]]*\{[^{]+authentication[[:blank:]]*\{[^}]+pre-shared-secret[[:blank:]]+'"$secret"

if [[ $TEXT =~ $pat ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.20
```

Please note that the regex above is tested against the given example only and may not be robust enough for an arbitrary input.